# NSIndexPath Leak

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, nsindexpath

I have a memory leak that is very puzzling! It happens when I tap the section Index and then scroll manually in a UITableView. It appears to be related to NSIndexPath, which I only read in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath. I don't create or store any NSIndexPath structures otherwise.

Other users had similar problem in earlier SDK versions and only within the simulator. I use the latest 4.2 and this leak appears both in the simulator and the device.

Below is a screenshot link. Any idea as to what causes this problem, or any tips on how to narrow it down without looking at assembly code?
http://www.maani.us/temp/Screenshot1.png
http://www.maani.us/temp/Screenshot2.png

Thank you.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this issue. Here are 2 more snapshots from the Leaks Instrument. Please help if you can:

Comment: http://www.maani.us/temp/Screenshot3.png

Comment: http://www.maani.us/temp/Screenshot4.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer (yet), but I was wondering if you're still seeing this behavior. I randomly see the same thing as described here. I also realize that the Profiler isn't perfect, so I'm considering that too.